# VS Community 2019: Memory could not be read

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I recently installed VS Community 2019, version 16.6.3 and when launching right after the splash screen is shown, I get the following error message:

[image]

I have reinstalled it twice and ran the repair service, and still get this error. Has anyone else experienced this and been able to fix it?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with VS Community 2019 itself. Did you try to reach out for support from Microsoft themselves? Is this the latest installation file from the microsoft website?

Comment: I sent a message on the VS forums, waiting to hear back. I'll post the problem and solution here once they do.